# How to extract all changed or added files from git history?

Tags: git, git-history

Have can I extract filename of modified/added files from git history of a project?
I need a list of modified/added files as a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the stats for a number of commits (range of hashes), you could just do:

```
git diff --stat <hash1> <hash2>
```

this will give you the stats for this range from hash1 to hash2.